# Visual Studio 2017 - JavaScript option to download remote references missing

Tags: javascript, intellisense, visual-studio-2017, javascript-intellisense

In VS 2015 there was an option at Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> JavaScript -> IntelliSense -> General to download any remote references you had linked into your script. This was very useful when dealing with third party libraries as it would lex out all your functions and properties for you, as well as help prevent typos.

I installed VS 2017 on a separate computer and this option is conspicuously absent from the same options dialogue.

Anyone know where it went or if I need to install some extension to get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VS2017 has a new implementation of the JavaScript language service (and IntelliSense).  It doesn't have full feature parity with the old language service (there's some new scenarios that work, and some old ones that don't).  Please file feedback for scenarios that are no longer working for you, so the JS team can be informed to prioritize those.

Comment: You can read more about the differences [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/javascript-intellisense)

Answer (score 2):

Use the reference tag for intellisense.  E.g.

```
///<reference path="http://domain/common.js"/>
```